# Getting an error 'unhashable type list' in python when working with a file and dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary, hash

for an assignment, I'm trying to to create a python dictionary. The dictionary's keys are a set of email addresses, which are stored in a list and the values are the amount of times each address appears in the list. Here is the code I'm using to create this dictionary. The object I'm iterating `addresses` is the list containing the email addresses. The error I get is 'unhashable type: list'. Any help would be useful.

```
count = {}
for j in addresses:
    count[addresses] = count.get(addresses, 0) + 1
```

Comment: You meant `count[j]=count.get(j, 0) +1`.

Comment: Did you google the error message? `addresses` is the list you are looping over; you want `count[i]`. Voting to close as typo/trivial. Maybe also google `defautdict` and `collections.Counter`.

Comment: I second what @tripleee said. Use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) instead: `count = Counter(addresses)`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So the error is that you do this

```
count[addresses] = count.get(addresses ...
```

while you're iterating over the list.

So as I understood, to fix that problem you need to write

```
count[j] = count.get(j ...
```

So the problem was, that you tried to put the data into the dictionary by the list, which does not have a `__hash__` method. To fix this you need to specify the key that is hashable, for example, string or integer.